# Weird behavior of two identical vectors

Tags: r

I have two "identical" vectors with the same length in R, x and y. Here is what they look like on my screen:

[image]

When I run:

```
plot(ecdf(x), 
     xlim = range(0.98,1), 
     col = "blue")

plot(ecdf(y), 
     add = TRUE, 
     lty = "dashed",
     col = "red")
```

I get:

[image]

Also, the ks.test produces:

[image]

The D value should be 0, and p-value 1.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on? I've tried modifing scipen and max.print options but that shows the same results as I thought maybe one vector's numbers was being truncated.

Comment: What does x-y look like in terminal?

Comment: This should probably be on Stackoverflow, but what does sum(x-y) return ?

Comment: It worked fine for me. `x <- rep(0.99, 100);
y <- rep(0.99, 100);
ks.test(x, y)`

Comment: This just screams floating point precision issues - your x and y probably differ in the seventeenth decimal or so. Try printing their full 64 bit representation in hex.

Comment: x-y was the showed the problem. Looks like small deviations on the 12th decimal place. I guess I could just round. Any suggestions on how to alleviate this problem besides rounding?

Comment: @Pareto What problem do you see? You ask if there is a difference, and the test catches a difference.

Comment: [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: @Dave well said. There is a difference and it did catch it. What i've got to do is a lot of ks.test's. Some show these types of deviations on a small scale (x) and others on a larger x scale. I need differentiate between those on a small and large scale (x's). It's almost like a need a ks.test more sensitive to deviation at which x varies. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Pareto It seems like an expansion on that question would warrant posting.

Comment: @Dave thanks! Will try and do that.

Comment: `ks.test` would have given you a clear warning if the values were identical, because it's not applicable when there are ties in the data (with a little grain of salt with a small proportion of ties).  So, using `ks.test` just doesn't make sense for your purpose unless you are trying to exploit its warning message!

Answer (score 1):

As deduced in the comments, the vectors are *not* identical, so the test worked correctly.

You asked in the comments:

> Any suggestions on how to alleviate this problem besides rounding?

It's fine to use rounding, but only round when you call the function. Don't round the data in place, (ie. don't do `x <- round(x,2)` unless that's what you really, really, want) - that could cause bias with whatever analysis you are doing further down the line:

```
x <- rep(0.99,100); y <- rep(0.992,100); ks.test(x,y)
##  Asymptotic two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## data:  x and y
## D = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16


ks.test(round(x,2),round(y,2))
##  Asymptotic two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## data:  round(x, 2) and round(y, 2)
## D = 0, p-value = 1
```